# How can I get the covariance matrix?

Tags: ros-humble, vio

I am using ROS2 Humble. I want to integrate the Odometry data with RTAB-SLAM. The odometry data is acquired from Visual Odometry. When I looked at the odometry msg format for publishing it, it needs the covariance value of both pose and twist. Unfortunately, I don't have these covariance matrixs.

Do you guys know how can i get the covariance matrix ? I really got stuck.